# Vue + axios - change variable if last request is done

Tags: vue.js, request, axios

I want change variable loading only, if the last request is done. Because now, it's changing he variable loading if the first request is done.

This is the code

```
fetchData(page_url) {
  const self = this;
  self.loading = true;
  axios.get(page_url)
      .then(res => {
        self.loading = false;
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
  });
}
```

UPDATE:

This is where I call fetchData

```
<b-input @keyup="fetchDataFromSearch()" v-model="searchstr" type="text" placeholder="Search" class="mb-2"></b-input>
```

```
fetchDataFromSearch() {
      this.new_search = true;
      let page_url = `${this.apiurl}?page=1&orderby=${this.orderby}&ordertype=${this.ordertype}`;
      if(this.searchstr !== '') page_url = `${this.apiurl}?page=1&orderby=${this.orderby}&ordertype=${this.ordertype}&search=${this.searchstr}`;
      this.fetchData(page_url);
    },
```

Comment: I see you are hitting only one request..

Comment: if i do fetchData multiple time i have more then 1 request

Comment: can you share the code where you call it repeatedly?

Comment: Checkout update

Comment: Check my updated logic

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this

```
fetchData(page_url) {
  const self = this;
  self.loading = true;
  return axios.get(page_url)
     .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
  });
}
```

and then the place where you need to call it repeatedly, intialize a promises array in your data and then keep pushing a promise everytime when you call it

```
this.promises.push(this.fetchData(page_url));
```

finally in the end you can resolve all the promises

```
Promise.all(this.promises).then(() => {
 this.loading = false;
});
```

Comment: And where do i put the function of resolving all promises. If i add it to mounted, it will only trigger once...

Comment: is there a function block where you iteratively call this function?

Comment: This is my complete code: https://jsfiddle.net/4rhptzgL/

Comment: You are invoking the method from watch...so there is no way we could determine when the last request hit happens

Comment: it's also in mounted

Comment: ya but it is triggered from different places like mounted, watch, from child component etc

Comment: So we cant predict the last request hit

Comment: But if i have it only in mounted, it won't work for a second time when fetchData is triggered...

Comment: ya thats obvious...this approach needs to be changed

Comment: And how? Can you please explain to me better?

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer now. The code should look something like this:

```
<scrtipt>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      loading: false,
      request: 0,
      requests: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    fetchData() {
      const self = this;
      self.requests = self.requests + 1;
      axios.get('/url')
        .then(res => {
          self.request = self.request + 1;
          if(self.requests == self.request) {
            self.loading = false;
          }
        }).catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
      });
    }
  }
}
</script>
```